# SQL Using two aggregate functions in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to create a query that output's `INV_NUM`, `INV_AMOUNT`, `AVG_INV`, and `DIFF` from a table called `INVOICE`.

I have this so far:

```
SELECT INV_NUM, 
       INV_AMOUNT, 
       (SELECT AVG(INV_AMOUNT) FROM INVOICE) AS AVG_INV 
FROM INVOICE;
```

I am very new to sql and am trying to figure out how to make

```
(SELECT SUM(INV_AUMOUNT - AVG(INV_AMOUNT) FROM INVOICE) AS DIFF
```

work. I have searched for a solution and am unable to implement something that works. Any assistance is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @trailmax I am doing a query in access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT i.INV_NUM, i.INV_AMOUNT, ai.avg_inv_amount,
       (i.INV_AMOUNT - ai.avg_inv_amount) as diff
FROM INVOICE as i,
     (SELECT AVG(INV_AMOUNT) as avg_inv_amount FROM INVOICE) as ai;
```